# text mining a txt file using python

Tags: python, text

Hello I am new to this site and python,

I was trying to import data from a txt file into python and it was only reading one tweet out of the several hundreds on there.

I have no idea what is wrong, please can someone help out.

this is the code:

```
tweets_data = []
tweets_file = open('unclassified_tweets.txt', "r")
for line in tweets_file:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        tweets_data.append(tweet)
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: To know *whats wrong*, remove the `except: continue` block.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to read all the lines in a file with Python is to use the `readlines()` function. However, it looks like you are reading JSON...

You should instead, then, take a look at the [Pandas `read_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) function. Pandas is a wonderful, powerful module for doing things like this.